# Subtract date returns negative

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
_intervals = intervalEndTime.Subtract(intervalStartTime).Hours;
```

intervalEndTime = 2009-11-11 16:00
intervalStartTime = 2009-11-11 08:00

makes _intervals contain -8. Howcome it gets to be -8? Removing 8 hours from 16 should be 8? I could switch to make it positive 8, but could someone explain this one abit?

```
        private int calcIntervalRows()
    {
        int _intervals = 0;

        switch (this.BookingObject.IntervalEntity.IntervalEntityID.Trim())
        {
            case "DAY":
                _intervals = 1;
                break;
            case "MIN":
                _intervals = SplitTime(new TimeSpan(intervalStartTime.Minute - intervalEndTime.Hour, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(this.BookingObject.IntervalValue != null ? this.BookingObject.IntervalValue.Value : 1, 0, 0));
                break;
            case "HOUR":
                _intervals = (int)intervalEndTime.Subtract(intervalStartTime).Hours;                    
                break;

        }

        return _intervals;
    }
```

[alt text http://svevarn.com/que.gif](http://svevarn.com/que.gif)

/M

Comment: Is there time travel involved?

Comment: Where's your cursor in the evaluation? If you're showing me the values before the statement was evaluated, _intervals could have -8 in it from a previous assignment.

Comment: What's the DateTimeKind of the two DateTimes involved? If one is UTC and the other is Local, that could explain it.

Comment: This code looks *very* suspicious: `intervalStartTime.Minute - intervalEndTime.Hour`

Comment: As the pragmatic guys say, "select isn't broken". What's better odds -- that you've found a bug in subtraction, or that there's a mistake in your code? *Find the bug.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 11, 11, 8, 0, 0);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2009, 11, 11, 16, 0, 0);

        Console.WriteLine(end.Subtract(start).Hours);
    }
}
```

Please check your start/end times are the right way round. If you can create a short but complete program like the above, but that demonstrates the problem, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You should use TimeSpan.TotalHours (and not Hours) when trying to get the difference between two times, especially if they are on different days.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I tried this in LINQPad and got 8

```
DateTime intervalEndTime = DateTime.Parse("2009-11-11 16:00");
DateTime intervalStartTime = DateTime.Parse("2009-11-11 08:00");
var _intervals = intervalEndTime.Subtract(intervalStartTime).Hours;
_intervals.Dump();
```